# Displaying actual progress in a JProgressBar?

Tags: java, progress-bar, splash-screen

I use a SplashScreen for my program. When the program is started, a lot of data is loaded from a database, the GUI is built, etc.
This all is summarized in one single class. So basically this class just does a lot of things, which take about 5 seconds. I'd like to create a SplashScreen with an accurate progress bar for it.

The SplashScreen itself without the progress bar is already finished. I'm able to handle the progress bar. **My only problem is that I don't know, how I can get the actual progress of building the class I mentioned before.**

*I looked that topic up on Google already. Everyone is just using a loop with some sleep-methods in it. I don't want this. I want to set the actual progress in this bar.*

What's the best way to do this? As I said, the class does a lot of things. Therefore it's not really an option to put a `.setProgress(...)` or something like that between every line of code. That wouldn't be really accurate anyway but yeah...

Is there even a way to solve it this way?